# Magento 2.2.4 How to override the styles for the Checkout Module?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2.4, styles

How to create specific style files that override the styles for the Magento Checkout Module?

I took a look at `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web` and `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/` but there are not style files there that I can copy to `app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/Magento_Checkout/...`

How to achieve this in a consistent way?

I tried to add the styling rule here: `app/design/frontend/XXX/XXX/web/css/source/_theme.less` and it worked, but I still do not know if this is the appropriate Magento way to do it, since it is something that has an impact on the checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file name **_extend.less** to your theme under the following directory:

> app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/web/css/source/_extend.less

You can use this throughout the website for custom css or less.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But the Checkout code will be loaded in all pages right?
How about extending it in:
*app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source*?

Answer (score 0):

Just override one of the layouts on **Magento Checkout** and add this code on the head `<css src="Magento_Checkout::css/site-theme.css"/>` and add the `site-theme.css` on the css folder